# javascript invalid regular expression: Unmatched ')'

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, sails.js

I've just added an admin panel hook in my project on sails.
I'm getting this error when I try to lift sails:

```
warn: Sails' built-in layout support only works with the `ejs`, `handlebars`, `ractive` view engines.
warn: You're using `jade`.
warn: Ignoring `sails.config.views.layout`...
```

and this error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\admin\(.*)\/?$/: Unmatched ')'
```

The config/view.js engine is set to jade, layout to false.

Comment: You're probably looking for `/^\admin(.*)\/?$/`.

Comment: The problem was in the adminpanel for sails.

Comment: @BorislavBankov how did you solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a string starting with `admin`, then followed by arbitrary number of any characters and an optional `/` at the end, use

```
/^admin(.*?)\/?$/
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJ7rU6/1)

When you escape a special character (like `(` or `)` here) they are treated as literals, and thus, your regex became corrupt. I also do not believe you want to match an `\a` (matches the bell character). If you meant to match a `\`, double it:

```
/^\\admin(.*?)\/?$/
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJ7rU6/2)

Note that if you use greedy matching with `(.*)`, you will also *capture* the final optional `/`. If you do not want to capture it (see the captured text in regex101 demo on the left), use lazy matching with `*?`.

Answer (score 1):

The \ is an escape character so it escaped the character that is following it. If you want to match just a `\`, you need to double you the `\\`.

```
/^\\admin\\(.*)\/?$/:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping the left parenthesis, causing the right parenthesis to be unmatched. Given your pattern, it should be  `/^\admin(.*)\/?$/`